# how to design seekbar with 3 thumbs?

Tags: android, android-canvas, seekbar

Can anyone suggest me how to design seekbar with 3 thumbs. is it possible with predefined android seekbar control. i thought that it can design by using canvas, because when user try to move thumbs proper value will be displayed in top of the thumb. i want to use canvas for this requirement is it correct way or not.

[image]

Comment: can you add image so that it will be more clear.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/
this may useful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can not use predefined android seekbar control to fulfill your need.

Range seekbar has two thumbs and you can customize it to show three thumbs. You can use below ref. link:
http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/range-seekbar/

Comment: you have to know about how to initialize and set seek bar between 30 to 80 in starting the applicaion and then work move normally 0 to 100

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom view to do that, it's quite simple actually.

all you have to do is override onTouchEvent  and onDraw